# Facebook page feed and photo

Tags: php, facebook

I want to show in my home the last feed of my Facebook page, I'm then hooking at this link:
https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=204770913907&format=json
The problem is that facebook provides images in this format:
https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151523034618908&set=a.10150426023073908.381002.204770913907&type=1

And then I'm trying to convert them in direct jpg format, but the variables listed in the link above does not help to make up what should be the following link:
https://fbcdn-sphotos-ga.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/733911_10151523034618908_777095662_n.jpg

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regexp to get the image from the content field

```
    preg_match('/.*(class="img" src=")([^"]+)(".*)/',$test,$matches);
echo $matches[2]; //img
```

Or use the facebook api to get your picture

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-pictures/